# Can't CodeSign iOS App. A valid provision profile could not be found

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, code-signing-certificate, code-signing-entitlements

I'm trying to test my app on device. I've a single user developer ID.
I followed Apple's guide and requested the certificates for Development/Distribuition and created a Team Provisioning Profile (The team name is my appleID name Felipe Lira)
I've checked in keychain, xCode and Member Center, all certificates are valid and the provisioning profile is installed correctly on device. Nevertheless, I'm getting this error:

```
Code Sign error: A valid provisioning profile matching the application's
Identifier 'com.myappleID.appName' could not be found
```

Since everything is alright with my certifice/profile I'm assuming this must be a problem related to my bundle identifier. To be honest, I'm not sure what name I should put... is there a way to check in the provisioning profile what name should I match?

also my app name has some special characters/blank spaces, in the bundle ID they appear as a '-'. Is this a problem?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier could not be found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13226284/valid-provisioning-profile-matching-the-applications-identifier-could-not-be-fo) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745333/a-valid-provisioning-profile-matching-the-applications-identifier-could-not?rq=1 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985611/a-valid-provisioning-profile-matching-the-applications-identifier-could-not?rq=1

Comment: Thanks. It was not the same solution but it sure helped. I was missing the 10CHARCODE before the .com.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bundleID should match the AppID in your developer portal account: "com.myappleID.appName". Or at least, something like "com.myappleID.*"

From Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html) you can use "using only the Roman alphabet in upper and lower case (A–Z, a–z), the dot (“.”), and the hyphen (“-”)" in the **BundleID**.

If you have different characters, you can put a different name for the app using the other property of the plist: **CFBundleDisplayName**

Hope it helps!

Comment: Since I had a team provisioning profile apple generated that 10CHARCODE. I put that before com.myname.appname and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

the "-" means you put a space in your app name since a bundle ID cannot have space apple will replace it with a hyphen.

Quick Fix

1. Xcode > check your project name
2. go to your plist info
3. make sure your bundle identifier match you IOS provisioning profile
   one

You can also harcode it , so remove the {$Product_name} and replace it with your app name

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a `Wildcard AppID`, you can have your `Bundle identifier` be anything as long as it's an appropriate string using the reverse-DNS format.

Go to your project .plist and change the "Bundle identifier" to **com.something.somthing**

Here is the on [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1713/_index.html) wildcard App ID vs. an explicit App ID

Comment: In my provision profile, under AppID was a 10CHARCODE. I figured out I had to put those 10 chars in my BundleID before everything and voila it worked.